# How to change the length of a Spinner in Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to Android development and I got a problem when adding a spinner view in Android.

I added the 2 spinners here with the xml code below:

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/input_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:theme="@style/MatchSpinnerTheme" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/output_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:theme="@style/MatchSpinnerTheme" />
```

But the length of the spinner is too long, how can change that?
[image]

Comment: By length do you mean width or height? Or both?

Comment: Well, I mean the whole part of the spinner. The spinner and the distance of the text to the select icon is too large. I wanna change that, to make it closer